# Rosegarden don't work

Tags: 11.10, multimedia, rosegarden

I recently installed Rosegarden. When it had ran for the first time, it worked excellent. After, I had to restart my computer and when I ran it for the second time, something strange was occurred: according to the System Monitor, Rosegarden was running, in spite of  I couldn't see the application, sometimes it's opened at other desktop and also Unity always has some instability problems like disappear the title bar of other programs or a zone is marked (for example, when we drag a window to the right side, we can see an "orange" area and the window's size is reduced to distribute at the middle of the desktop) at the left side of the screen and isn't hidden.

Comment: Can you provide more information, such as: how does it appear to be running if you can't see anything, what does ps report, what did you do to reset it, etc

Comment: Ok, I added more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe deleting your metadata would help? See this answer for more details.

[Very strange rosegarden crash issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45022/very-strange-rosegarden-crash-issue)

I'd put this in a comment If I could.

Comment: Well, I had to delete ~/.config/rosegardenmusic/ to start Rosegarden. The main detail is to set up it OK to prevent another error. A little strange behaviour is that Rosegarden appears in other Workspace. It would be a bug.

Comment: See if you know how to answer my unrelated rosegarden question @BrallanAguilar http://askubuntu.com/questions/85185/rosegarden-plugin-list-is-empty